# Finding a matrix knowing determinant

Tags: matrices

> Suppose $\det A = 1$ and you know all the cofactors. How can you find $A$?

So my attempt was taking the formula $A^{-1} = C^T/\det A$.

If $\det A = 1$ then $A^{-1} = C^T$.
And now we also know that $\det A^{-1} = 1$ and $\det C^T = 1$.

The solution says that "Since $A$ is the inverse matrix of $A^{-1}$, $A$ must be the cofactor matrix of $C$".

How?? Isn't $C$ the cofactor matrix of $A$? 
I'm very confused about this sentence...

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that $A^{-1}=C^T/\det A$, taking inverses gives $A=(C^T/\det A)^{-1}=(C^{-1})^T$ since $\det A=1$. So $C^{-1}=A^T$ and since $\det C=1$, $A$ is the cofactor matrix of $C$.